# encoding between Axis2 and Apache Commons Email

Tags: java, email, character-encoding, apache-axis, apache-commons-email

I've got the following webservice method, which is called by REST:

```
public boolean sendMail(String text) {
    Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setHostName(MAIL_SERVER);
    email.setSmtpPort(25);
    email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(MAIL_USER, MAIL_PASSWORD));
    try {
        email.setFrom(MAIL_SENDER);
        email.setSubject(text);
        email.setMsg(text);
        email.addTo(MAIL_RECEIVER);
        email.send();
        return true;
    } catch (EmailException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The request is like `sendMail?text=aäoöuü` which is encode with `x-www-form-urlencoded` to
`sendMail?text=a%E4o%F6u%FC`

The content of the mail is `a?o?u?`.

Mail API is [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/).

How can I get the right character encoding to the mail?

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the parameter using UTF-8 before applying the URL encoding.